# Pandas - splitting dataframe into equal rows and assign number in new column as case_id in increasing order from 1 and so on

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chunks

I have a large dataframe that consists of more than 100000 rows. I want to divide the rows into an equal number of chunks, let's say 4, and create a new column *case_id* and assign number 1 to this group of 4 rows.

```
id    col1   col2
0     A      A
1     B      B
2     C      C
3     D      D
4     E      E
5     F      F
6     G      G
7     H      H
```

column *id* is starting from 0.

Desired output:

```
id    col1   col2    new_col_case_id
0     A      A       1
1     B      B       1
2     C      C       1
3     D      D       1
4     E      E       2
5     F      F       2
6     G      G       2
7     H      H       2
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

n = 4 # number of rows in each chunk
data = {"id": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        "col1": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"],
        "col2": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
length = len(df)
df["new_col_case_id"] = df["id"].apply(lambda x: int(x/n) + 1)
df = df.set_index("id") #optional
print(df)
```

output:

```
   col1 col2  new_col_case_id
id                           
0     a    a                1
1     b    b                1
2     c    c                1
3     d    d                1
4     e    e                2
5     f    f                2
6     g    g                2
7     h    h                2
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I tried this, but the new col "case_id" is having numbers as a group of 2 and not 4. sorry, I'm new to python and this may be very annoying.

Comment: @Syntax do you mean that you want the number 4 as the number of rows in the chunk?

Comment: I have added desired output in question. I want 4 rows to have a similar number such as 1 to the first 4 rows and then 2 to the next 4 rows and so on.

Comment: @Syntax, I updated the code, now it should work as you desired it in the first place